How to pass arguments to cleveref
I am trying to write my own theorem package which wraps a bunch of functions to order my standard preamble. In doing so I got stuck with the following problem: I try to create a function to define a new theorem-like environment and the corresponding cleveref names -- both in a single method by a single call. However, for some reason I can't get this work.
Below a minimal example with two approaches, the former is what I would naturally do, in the latter I try to use the latex3 syntax in which I am currently writing the broader package (which is to say: I guess for this problem this seems a bit over the top, I still included it because this is closer to my actual use case).
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

% Version A
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfooA}{m m m m}{
    \newtheorem{#1}{#2}
    \Crefname{#1}{#3}{#4}
}

% Version B
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfooB}{m m m m}{
    \newtheorem{#1}{#2}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_crefname_tl {#1}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_name_tl {#3}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_names_tl {#4}
    \cs_set:Npn \l_mycrefname_cs ##1##2##3 {\Crefname{##1}{##2}{##3}}
    \exp_args:Nooo \l_mycrefname_cs \l_crefname_tl \l_name_tl \l_names_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Test Version A
\myfooA{defA}{Definition}{Definition A}{Definitions A}
\begin{defA}\label{defA}
    Some Definition A
\end{defA}
\Cref{defA}


% Test Version B
\myfooB{defB}{Definition}{Definition B}{Definitions B}
\begin{defB}\label{defB}
    Some Definition B
\end{defB}
\Cref{defB}

\end{document}

In both cases I get the error message:
LaTeX: Cref reference format for label type `defA' undefined.

respectively the same for \defB.
Does any of you know what is going on here, respectively what I am doing wrong here?

The expl3 syntax you propose is broadly wrong. You're basically doing (with bad naming of functions and variables) a complicated version of \Crefname{#1}{#3}{#4}. There's no need to store the arguments in variables just to use them in the next step: it's just a waste of time.

Which is pretty much what I try to say in the bracket. I wrote this version because where I actually use this I don’t have the #1 etc but actually variables from another routine. So that version is to make sure that the conversion to expl3 is somewhat correct.
Moreover I would appreciate it if instead of just the opinion „that code is ugly“ you also shared some constructive suggestion for improvement. I am new to expl3 so don’t expect a masterpiece of code from me. It would be helpful to understand why those names are so wrong for example.

Functions (the one you define with \cs_set:Npn) should not have l_ in front of them and should end with a signature, in your case :nnn rather than _cs. A name like \l_name_tl is bad because it should be \l_<prefix>_<proper name>_tl. Having fixed prefixes reduces the risk of naming conflicts. Also o-expansion is not the right tool: you want V argument type.

Both of your commands work provided they are defined and called within the preamble of the document.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfooA}{m m m m}{
    \newtheorem{#1}{#2}
    \Crefname{#1}{#3}{#4}
}

% Version B
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfooB}{m m m m}{
    \newtheorem{#1}{#2}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_crefname_tl {#1}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_name_tl {#3}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_names_tl {#4}
    \cs_set:Npn \l_mycrefname_cs ##1##2##3 {\Crefname{##1}{##2}{##3}}
    \exp_args:Nooo \l_mycrefname_cs \l_crefname_tl \l_name_tl \l_names_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\myfooA{defA}{Definition}{Definition A}{Definitions A}
\myfooB{defB}{Definition}{Definition B}{Definitions B}


\begin{document}
% Version A


% Test Version A

\begin{defA}\label{defA}
    Some Definition A
\end{defA}
\Cref{defA}


% Test Version B

\begin{defB}\label{defB}
    Some Definition B
\end{defB}
\Cref{defB}

\end{document}



Ah, thanks for the very quick reply! That is very helpful!!
I assume the need to put this into the preamble is likely due to the referencing logic and nothing one could change by simple means?

@uzer.name Yes, I think so. I'm not too familiar with the internals of cleveref but it seems like it's not something that could easily be overridden. Which makes sense, since in general such commands are logically placed in the preamble and not the main document.

cleveref does a lot of work at begin document. Defining theorem-like environments after \begin{document} defies it.

The code for defining theorem-like environments should go in the preamble, because it's a “global” setting.
The expl3 code you're using is bad in several places. Here's a cleaned up version.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definetheorem}{m m m m}
  {
    \newtheorem{#1}{#2}
    \uzername_crefname:nnn { #1 } { #3 } { #4 }
  }

\tl_new:N \l_uzername_crefname_tl
\tl_new:N \l_uzername_name_tl
\tl_new:N \l_uzername_names_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \uzername_crefname_make:nnn {} % initialize
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \uzername_crefname_make:nnn { VVV }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \uzername_crefname:nnn #1#2#3
% alternative, using signature instead of parameter text:
% \cs_new_protected:Nn \uzername_crefname:nnn 
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_uzername_crefname_tl {#1}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_uzername_name_tl {#2}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_uzername_names_tl {#3}
    \cs_set_protected:Npn \uzername_crefname_make:nnn ##1##2##3 {\Crefname{##1}{##2}{##3}}
    \uzername_crefname_make:VVV \l_uzername_crefname_tl \l_uzername_name_tl \l_uzername_names_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

I don't understand why setting the function every time, though.

Thanks for this very helpful input! I took the liberty to fix a minor typo in the code. Do I understand your last sentence correct that it would be good practice to move the \cs_set_protected:Npn \uzername_crefname_make:nnn ##1##2##3 {\Crefname{##1}{##2}{##3}} to the outer level (i.e. outside the definition of \uzername_crefname:nnn )?

@uzer.name Yes, of course it would be good practice. But using \cs_new_protected:Npn, of course.
